# Why do I need to overide "onPlaceRequest" in every Presenter class?

Tags: java, gwt, history, gwt-history

I'm managing the History in my project via Places.

What I do is this:

- implement PlaceRequestHandler on top level (for example AppController),
- register it -> eventBus.addHandler(PlaceRequestEvent.getType(), this);
- implement method "onPlaceRequest" ,where i do project navigation.

I'm using GWT presenter and every presenter in my project overrides the `onPlaceRequest` method.

**Why do I need this, when every request is handled from the top level "onPlaceRequest" method?**

I will give an example:

```
public class AppController implements Presenter, PlaceRequestHandler
...........
public void bind()
{
  eventBus.addHandler(PlaceRequestEvent.getType(), this);
...
}
public void onPlaceRequest(PlaceRequestEvent event)
{
// here is the project navigation tree
}
```

and let's take one presenter

```
public class SomePresenter extends Presenter<SomePresenter.Display>
{
... here some methods are overriden and 

@Override
protected void onPlaceRequest(PlaceRequest request)
{
// what should I do here? 
}
}
```

What is the idea, and how I'm supposed to use it?

Comment: Too bad that you deleted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229931/jsf-problem-when-dispalying-userbean-properties while I was typing a world class answer. At least, it boils down to that you was reading world's worst Java EE tutorial. Put roseindia.net in your Internet blacklist!

Comment: hi BalusC, sorry about that. I did't know that and i thought that the question is not interesting to anyone. You are right about roseindia.net...

Comment: Not interesting to anyone? Did you expect answers within minutes? C'mon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of making all of your presenters extend  `PlaceRequestHandler` and managing those events yourself, you can attach a  `PlaceHistoryHandler` and a `PlaceController` to your event bus. Together, they manage the browser's history and your places for you.  When you ask your `PlaceController` to goTo() a different place, it will stop your current activity and use a mapping of places to activities (your presenters) to choose which one to start next.

To use this technique, you need to have your presenters extend `AbstractActivity`. Try following through Google's tutorial about it in GWT's documentation called [GWT Development with Activities and Places](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html).